# label.configure works sometimes why?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Part of my code is as follows:

```
def get_songs():
    label6.configure(text='Wait')
    os.system('/home/norman/my-startups/grabsongs')
    label6.configure(text='Done')
```

The label is not updated at the first `.configure()` but is at the second one.
Except if I cause a deliberate error immediately after the first one at which point it is updated and then the program terminates.
The system call takes about 2 minutes to complete so it isn't as if there isn't time to display the first one.

I am using Python 2.7.6

Does anyone know why please?

Comment: I think I fixed your indentation.  Please feel free to edit again if I indented it incorrectly -- Also, you haven't specified what type of object `label` _is_.  My guess is that it's a `tkinter.Label` from looking at it, but you should probably edit that information into your post somewhere (or tag the question with `tkinter`).

Comment: [`root.update_idletasks()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) or using a [`StringVar()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) in combination with the [`textvariable` option of the label](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) could do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess you're using `Tkinter`.  If so, as @albert just suggested, you'll want to call `label.update_idletasks()` or `label.update()` to tell Tkinter to refresh the display.

As a very crude example to reproduce your problem, let's make a program that will:

1. Wait 1 second
2. Do something (sleep for 2 seconds) and update the text to "wait"
3. Display "done" afterwards

For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Not waiting yet')
label.pack()

def do_stuff():
    label.configure(text='Wait')
    time.sleep(2)
    label.configure(text='Done')

label.after(1000, do_stuff)
tk.mainloop()
```

Notice that "Wait" will never be displayed.

To fix that, let's call `update_idletasks()` after initially setting the text:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Not waiting yet')
label.pack()

def do_stuff():
    label.configure(text='Wait')
    label.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
    label.configure(text='Done')

label.after(1000, do_stuff)
tk.mainloop()
```

---

As far as why this happens, it actually is because Tkinter doesn't have time to update the label.

Calling `configure` doesn't automatically force a refresh of the display, it just queues one the next time things are idle.  Because you immediately call something that will halt execution of the mainloop (calling an executable and forcing python to halt until it finishes), Tkinter never gets a chance to process the changes to the label.

Notice that while the gui displays "Wait" (while your process/sleep is running) it won't respond to resizing, etc.  Python has halted execution until the other process finishes running.

To get around this, consider using `subprocess.Popen` (or something similar) instead of `os.system`.  You'll then need to perodically poll the returned pipe to see if the subprocess has finished.

As an example (I'm also moving this into a class to keep the scoping from getting excessively confusing):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import subprocess

class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(parent, text='Not waiting yet')
        self.label.pack()
        self.parent.after(1000, self.do_stuff)

    def do_stuff(self):
        self.label.configure(text='Wait')
        self._pipe = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sleep', '2'])
        self.poll()

    def poll(self):
        if self._pipe.poll() is None:
            self.label.after(100, self.poll)
        else:
            self.label.configure(text='Done')

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

The key difference here is that we can resize/move/interact with the window while we're waiting for the external process to finish.  Also note that we never needed to call `update_idletasks`/`update`, as Tkinter now does have idle time to update the display.

Comment: Thanks guys, I added the {label.update_idletasks()} and it works now.

Comment: @Buteman: If so, please accept the answer in order to close your question and mark it as answered